# Lower Bound for Cosine restricted to a Circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Prove that $|\cos z|\geq 1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ lying on the circle of radius $n\pi$, centered at the origin.

In other words, prove that $|\cos(n\pi e^{i\theta})|\geq 1$ for all real $\theta$ and $n=1,2,3,\dots$.

What is the most elegant way to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(x+iy) = \cos x \cosh y - i \sin x \sinh y$ so $$|\cos(x+iy)|^2 = \cos^2 x \cosh^2 y + \sin^2 x \sinh^2 y = \dfrac{\cos(2x)}{2} + \dfrac{\cosh(2y)}{2}$$

On the lines $x = \pm n \pi \pm y$, $\cos(2x) = \cos(2y)$ so 
$$|\cos(x+iy)|^2 = \frac{\cos(2y)+\cosh(2y)}{2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2y)^{4n}}{(4n)!} \ge 1$$
Now $\cosh(2y)$ is an increasing function of $|y|$, and the square with vertices $[\pm n\pi, 0]$ and $[0,\pm n\pi]$ is inscribed in the circle $|x+iy|=n\pi$, so $|\cos(x+iy)|^2 \ge 1$ on that circle.

Comment: Fantastic, Robert! What a clever strategy. Thanks!